# $x^3+x^2y^2+y^3=7$, and solvable families of Diophantine equations

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

(a) Do there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^3+x^2y^2+y^3=7$ ?

(b) Is this equation belongs to some family $F$ of equations for which there is a known algorithms for testing if they have an integer solution? For example, such algorithms are known for quadratic equations (in $n$ variables) and for cubic equations in 2 variables, but this equation has degree 4.

(c) Reference request: can you recommend a good book/survey/website which would help to determine if a given (reasonably simple) Diophantine equation belong to some solved case, or is new?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(a) No. There are no integer solutions. The curve $C$ you give has genus $3$ and it has an obvious automorphism $\phi(x,y) = (y,x)$. The quotient curve is an elliptic curve. In particular, if you let $X = -(x+y)$ and $Y = xy$, then the equation becomes $E : Y^{2} + 3XY = X^{3} + 7$. So any integer point on your curve gives rise to an integer point on $E$. As you note, cubic equations in two variables have algorithms for finding their integer points. This elliptic curve has rank $1$ and its integral points are $(-3,4)$, $(-3,5)$, $(186,-2831)$ and $(186,2273)$. None of these lead to integer points on $C$.

(b) There are not many general families of such curves. For curves of genus $0$, there are algorithms for finding their integer points. For curves of genus $1$, the existing procedures rely on being able to compute the Mordell-Weil group and it is currently open whether there is an algorithm to do so. One other family that might be worth mentioned is the family of [Thue equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue_equation), those of the form $F(x,y) = k$ where $k$ is a constant and $F$ is a homogeneous polynomial in two variables.

(c) For a survey of what number theorists can and cannot handle algorithmically, you might consult Henri Cohen's book "Number Theory, Volume I: Tools and Diophantine Equations." Chapter 6 in that book gives a nice survey of simple Diophantine equations together with some techniques that might suffice to handle those. The class of equations that can be definitely be handled in a systematic or algorithmic way is quite small. (If I had been unable to compute the Mordell-Weil group of $E$ above, the software would not have been able to provably find all the integral points.)

Comment: Thank you, Jeremy!

Answer (score 3):

Let me post an elementary answer to this question, which I have found recently.

(a) Assume that $(x,y)$ is an integer solution. From symmetry, we may assume that $|y|\geq |x|$. If fact, cases $|y|=|x|$, $|y|=|x|+1$, and $|x|\leq 3$ can be checked directly, hence we may assume that $|y|\geq |x|+2>5$.
Now rewrite the equation as
$$
(x^2+y)(y^2+x)=xy+7,
$$
from which it follows that
$$
k = \frac{xy+7}{y^2+x}
$$
is an integer. However,
$$
y^2+x \geq |y|(|x|+2)-|x|=|xy|+2|y|-(|y|-2)=|xy|+|y|+2>|xy|+7\geq |xy+7|
$$
hence $|k|<1$, and it can be an integer only if $k=0$, or $xy+7=0$, which is impossible for $|y|\geq |x|+2>5$.

(b) This equation belongs to family of equations satisfying Runge's condition, for which there exists a general algorithms, see, for example

Walsh, P. A quantitative version of Runge's theorem on Diophantine equations, Acta Arithmetica, 62, 157--172, 1992.